# The meaning of three different expectation of conditional distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

When I read a paper, I found that there are three different kinds of the expectation of conditional distributions. But I am really confuse about these three notation.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

$$1.E_{Y|x}[\phi(Y)]$$
$$2.E_{Y|x}[\phi(Y)|x]$$
$$3.E_{Y|X}[\phi(Y)|X]$$

Comment: Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have already fixed the problems. Thank you for your suggestion. :)